# Common ratio of a GP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question:
If $f$ is a function satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ that are natural numbers; such that $f(1) = 3$ and $$\sum^{n}_{x=1}f(x) = 120$$ find the value of n.

I don't understand what they mean by the function satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$. Please explain this to me?

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

HINT : Note that$$f(x+1)=f(x)f(1)=3f(x).$$

Comment: Makes sense now. But how would I proceed from there?

Comment: @Gummybears: From what I wrote, you can get $f(2)=3^2,f(3)=3^3,f(4)=3^4,\cdots.$ So?

Comment: @Gummybears: Since $f(x)=3^x$, we have $\sum_{x=1}^{n}f(x)=\sum_{x=1}^{n}3^x=(3^{n+1}-3)/2$. So you can solve $(3^{n+1}-3)/2=120$ to get the $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is given as a *functional* equation. It is defined implicitly, in terms of itself, instead of explicitly in terms of a formula relating domain and codomain.

Note the following: $$f(2)=f(1+1) = f(1)f(1) = 3\cdot 3 = 9.$$ Then, $$f(3) = f(2)f(1) = f(1+1)f(1)=f(1)f(1)f(1) = 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 27.$$ In general, $$f(k) = f(1+1+\cdots +1) = f(1)^{k} =3^k.$$ So, your sum is $\sum_{k = 1}^n 3^ k$. Write out the first couple of summands to see when it equals 120.

**Also:** If you are interested in learning more about functional equations, I would recommend playing around with *Cauchy's functional equation* $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ defined on the rationals. Is there anything you can say about the general form of this function?

Comment: Isn't this answer and all others here adress the sum $$ f(\sum_{x = 1}^n x)  $$??? And isn't OP asking for $$ \sum_{x = 1}^n f(x)  $$? Or is it a typo from OP or am I missing something?

Comment: OP is asking for a particular value of $n$. No, your first sum is not in the replies; $f\left(\sum_{x =1}^n 1\right)$ is, though. I believe the replies are on the mark.

Comment: Is trial and error the only way to get to the sum? Isn't there a more concrete method?

Answer (score 0):

Choose some integer $x$ and $y$ to work it out. For example if you choose $x=1$ and $y=1$, you can derive that $f(1+1) = f(1)f(1) = 3\cdot 3 = 9$. So, now you also know $f(2)=9$. It should be pretty straighforward from there.